# Python pydantic model passing None as int value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a model which takes a few inputs including a sourceSiteId. This is an integer but also has many values as `None`. I have tried a few things with the model but still receive an error of `value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)` when the value is `None`. Below is my model.

```
class LatLongModel(BaseModel):
    # id: str
    object_id: Optional[int] = None
    primo_id: Optional[int] = None
    name: Optional[str] = None
    entity_type: Optional[str] = None
    division_id: Optional[int] = None
    division: Optional[str] = None
    status: Optional[str] = None
    longitude: Optional[float] = None
    latitude: Optional[float] = None
    site_id: Optional[int] = None
    source_site_id: Optional[int] = None
    site_type: Optional[str] = None
```

I have also tried to do `source_site_id: int = None` and `source_site_id: Optional[int]` but no luck. What can I try to get this model to accept integers as well as None type for source_site_id?

Comment: MRE?  off the top of my head this shouldn't happen, but memory could be faulty.

Answer (score 2):

Some background, a field type `int` will [try to coerce the value](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#standard-library-types) of `None` (or whatever you pass in) as an `int`. You can override this behavior by including a custom validator:

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class LatLongModel(BaseModel):
    # id: str
    object_id: Optional[int] = None
    primo_id: Optional[int] = None
    name: Optional[str] = None
    entity_type: Optional[str] = None
    division_id: Optional[int] = None
    division: Optional[str] = None
    status: Optional[str] = None
    longitude: Optional[float] = None
    latitude: Optional[float] = None
    site_id: Optional[int] = None
    source_site_id: Optional[int] = None
    site_type: Optional[str] = None


    # Custom validator here
    @validator('site_id', 'source_site_id', pre=True)
    def allow_none(cls, v):
        if v is None:
             return None
        else:
            return v
```

Comment: Thank you! I would add `or np.isnan(v)` since I couldn't spot it with just `v is None`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find the issue by defining a `__new__` method in your model. It might help you catch the problematic value(s) (empty string or something else) :

```python
class LatLongModel(BaseModel):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            print(f"'{k}' : {v.__repr__()} ({type(v)})")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    # [...]
    source_site_id: Optional[int] = None

l = LatLongModel(source_site_id="")

> 'source_site_id' : '' (<class 'str'>)
> Stacktrace [...] pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for LatLongModel
source_site_id
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```